# Windows feature that makes cursor turn into block in a text box

Tags: windows, google-chrome, text-cursor

I have searched around online and cannot seem to find an adequate answer to my question.

Every once in a while, I accidentally press some key combination on my keyboard that makes my cursor turn from the regular thin vertical line to a blue box that acts and behaves the exact same as the regular cursor but looks different.

[image: (Screenshot of the irregular cursor)]

Since this only affects the cursor while I am in Google Chrome, I assume it is a setting in Chrome, but I don't know. It also appears to be a problem isolated to one tab at a time, which to me is baffling.

It annoys me and the only way I know of to make it go away is to restart my computer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey, have you tried pressing the "Insert" key on your keyboard? It's usually located near the "Home" and the "Delete" buttons. Hope this works for you!

Comment: Yes. @Bungicasse That worked. Make it an answer and I will mark it correct. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to press the "Insert" key on your keyboard - It's usually located near the "Home" and the "Delete" buttons. This will make the cursor back to normal again.

Comment: huhhh!!!! saved my day